# PostgreSQL "column does not exist" error in CartoDB

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, cartodb

I'm currently working on a query that should return a *subset* of a CartoDB table (i.e. a new table) sorted by proximity to a given point. I want to display labels on the map corresponding to the closest, second closest, etc. and thought to capture that by using the PostgreSQL row_number() method in a new column:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    ST_Distance(
        ST_GeomFromText('Point(-73.95623080000001 40.6738101)', 4326)::geography,
        the_geom::geography
    ) / 1609 AS dist,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dist) as rownum
FROM locations
WHERE ST_Intersects(
   ST_GeomFromText(
      'Point(-73.95623080000001 40.6738101)', 4326
   ),
   the_geom
)
ORDER BY dist ASC
```

However, when I try this, CartoDB/PostgreSQL returns the following error:

```
Error: column "dist" does not exist
```

Any suggestions on a better approach or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **CANT** use a field calculated on the same level.

```
SELECT (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-x2)^2  as dist, dist * 1.6 as miles
                                       ^^^^^
                                    undefined
```

So you create a subquery.

```
SELECT dist * 1.6 as miles
FROM ( SELECT (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-x2)^2  as dist
       FROM table
     ) T
```

Comment: Interesting - If the main query is long and complex, is there a better "design" strategy than moving everything into a subquery? Specifically, if there is other data being queried for (such as * from the above example) how can that be accessed outside of the subquery?

Comment: I just simplify the problem to ilustrate the solution. But yes, you have to create a subquery with `*` and the calculated field

Comment: Even a 'non calculated field' cannot be used as such.

Comment: sorry dont understand what you mean?

Comment: `SELECT x as y, y+1 as z` - still invalid. No newly introduced column can be used (even there was no calculation done on `x`).

Comment: Yes, the problem is all select fields are processed at same time, so the interpreted doesnt know you change the name until the select is resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a column alias in another column. Here you are defining `dist` for result list and also use it in the `row_number`'s `ORDER BY`. You have to write the same expression that you used for `order` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dist) as rownum
FROM(
SELECT
    *,
    ST_Distance(
        ST_GeomFromText('Point(-73.95623080000001 40.6738101)', 4326)::geography,
        the_geom::geography
    ) / 1609 AS dist
FROM locations
WHERE ST_Intersects(
   ST_GeomFromText(
      'Point(-73.95623080000001 40.6738101)', 4326
   ),
   the_geom
)
) i
ORDER BY dist ASC
```

You can't access an alias from the same select so put it inside an inner query

Answer (score 1):

While one can use a derived inner query (which may be easier to read and can be optimized away pursuant to other RA rules), it is also possible to use *ordinals* to refer to columns as the restriction only applies to newly introduced *names*.

For example, the following is valid:

```
SELECT
    ST_Distance(
        ST_GeomFromText('Point(-73.95623080000001 40.6738101)', 4326)::geography,
        the_geom::geography
    ) / 1609 AS dist
  -- column ordering changed to make ordinal obvious, as * can bite
  -- now column 'dist' is the first column and can be referenced by ordinal
  , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY 1) as rownum
  , *
FROM locations
WHERE ST_Intersects(
   ST_GeomFromText(
      'Point(-73.95623080000001 40.6738101)', 4326
   ),
   the_geom
)
-- this could also be written as ORDER BY 1 ASC, per ordinal
ORDER BY dist ASC
```

Comment: Interesting! This approach seems to be structured more sanely than using a subquery.

Comment: @romeboards I would say 'less intrusively'. *However,* it can also lead to 'silent breakages'; imagine that someone comes along that changes the column positions and didn't notice the ordinal usage - now the query might still be valid syntax, but yield the wrong results. This is one reason for moving the `*` after, to avoid a column implicitly slipping in. In any case, it's an available approach.