# How to search for events in 5 km radius

Tags: mysql, join, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to select events in a 5 km radius and order them by likes and from oldest to newest. I know how to select events and order them by likes, but I can't figure this one out. The problem maybe is that the location is stored in a different table.

Database structure:

```
event        plusone (like)  location
id_event     id_plusone      id_location
location_id  event_id        lat
...          user_id         lon
             ...             city_id
                             full_name
                             ....
```

The SQL statement I'm trying:

```
    SELECT 3956 * 2 * ASIN(
        SQRT(POWER(SIN((50.127946 - abs(l.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(50.127946 * pi()/180 ) *
            COS(abs(l.lat) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((14.4882912 - l.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance,e.*,COUNT( p.id_plusone ) AS
            likes
    FROM
        event e,location l
        LEFT JOIN plusone p ON p.event_id = e.id_event
    WHERE
        e.location_id = l.id_location AND distance<=5 GROUP BY e.id_event
            ORDER BY e.timestamp DESC,likes DESC
```

The huge column at the beginning is calculation of distance of the event from user position using latitude and longitude.

This is what I get from the SQL debugger:

`#1054 - Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'`

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Dont mix `JOIN ON` sintaxis with old and obsolete `where a.id = b.id`. Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Seems like you're using the wrong dash character (`–` instead of `-`)

Comment: To me the `–` character looks suspicious. I think it should be `-`, so you have a long dash instead of the standard minus character. Btw, did you know that mysql has spatial data types and functions?

Comment: Yes, it was the "-" character; however it still doesn't work, I'll update the question.

Comment: If a question is answered, but a new issue comes to light, then you should not edit the question, but close this one down and post a new one.

Comment: The question is not awnsered, I need to select data, not get an error message.

Comment: I answer this one yesterday ... you cant use the alias at the same level...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738385/postgresql-column-does-not-exist-error-in-cartodb/35738448#35738448

Comment: @AdamBečvář he mean after the change you have a different error, so that mean a different question to be answer.

Comment: Ok I solved it after all, thank you though.

Comment: The #1054 is solved by moving `distance<=5` from the `WHERE` clause to a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Yes, thats what I did eventualy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is hard to track where the error is, you should try to solve the distance part first.

```
SELECT 
       event_id,
       3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((50.127946 - abs(l.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) 
     + COS(50.127946 * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(l.lat) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((14.4882912 – l.lon) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance,
FROM event e
JOIN location l 
WHERE distance <= 5
```

And then join to back to the `event` table

```
SELECT  e.*, count(p.id_plusone)
FROM event e
LEFT JOIN plusone p 
       ON p.event_id = e.id_event 
JOIN ( Previous Distance Query) d
  ON e.event_id = d.event_id 
GROUP BY e.id_event
ORDER BY e.timestamp DESC, likes DESC
```

and btw, this `group_by` will bring you `event_id` plus random values for `e.*` so be carefull

Comment: Hi, I followed your advice and it is working now, so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$latitudeD= latitude;
$longitudeD = longitude;

SELECT event,
        SQRT(
            POW(69.1 * (coordX - $latitudeD), 2) +
            POW(69.1 * ($longitudeD - coordY) * COS(coordX / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
        FROM db.table WHERE SQRT(
            POW(69.1 * (coordX - $latitudeD), 2) +
            POW(69.1 * ($longitudeD - coordY) * COS(coordX / 57.3), 2))  < 50 ORDER BY distance
        ;
```

Comment: Why do you mix php into this?